# I have used the flood fill algorithm however I'm not getting the expected output

Tags: python

I'm new to python and for an exercise
I'm supposed to create a go game. I don't understand where it has gone wrong for the output to be different from the expected, can someone please tell me where i have gone wrong for the output to be wrong

According to the exercise description,
In the Board class, i need to define a method `fill_reaching(self, colour_name, reach_name,` `visited, r, c)` that receives the following parameters `colour_name`: the name of the colour (`"E"`, `"B"`, or `"W"`) of the chain to be marked `reach_name`: the name of a colour to be tested for reachability `visited`: a matrix (list of lists) of Booleans of the same size as the board `r`, `c`: the row and column number indexed from 0, i.e. 0, 0 is the top left corner

it executes the flood fill algorithm, starting from the position given by `r` and `c`, to *mark* all points of colour `colour_name` that are connected to the starting position by a path of colour `colour_name` moving only vertically and horizontally. The method modifies the matrix `visited`: *marking* a point is defined as setting the corresponding element in `visited` to `True`. Some elements of `visited` may be `True` to begin with – the corresponding grid points are treated as if they were of a colour different from `colour_name`, this method must not modify the board object and In addition to marking all visited points, the method returns `True` if the starting point *reaches* the colour specified in `reach_name` (see rule #3) and `False` otherwise.

rule 3

[image]

The black point marked with a triangle *reaches empty* because there is a path of (vertically or horizontally adjacent) black points, marked with circles, to a point coloured empty (marked with a square).

The white point below the triangle does not reach empty. By following a path of white points only vertically or horizontally, you only ever reach black, not empty.

A *legal position* is a position in which every point coloured black or white reaches empty. The example above is not a legal position because there are points coloured white that don’t reach empty.

It is a consequence of the rules that every valid move creates a legal position. This is because according to rule #7, both colours are *cleared*, removing any stones that don’t reach empty.

```
def load_board(filename):
    result = "  "
    with open(filename) as f:

        print(f)
        for index, line in enumerate(f):
            if index == 0:
                result += ' '+' '.join([chr(alphabets + 65) for alphabets in range(len(line) - 1)]) + '\n'  # the alphabetical column heading
            result += f"{19 - index:2d}"
            result += ' ' + ' '.join(line.strip()) + '\n'
        return result



def save_board(filename, board):
    with open(filename, "wt") as f:
        f.write(str(board))
        

from string import ascii_uppercase as letters
class Board:
#Dictionary created for the colours and the respected symbols
    points = {'E': '.', 'B': '@', 'W': 'O'}

#Constructor
    def __init__(self,size=19,from_strings=None):
        assert 2 <= size <= 26, "Illegal board size: must be between 2 and 26."
        if from_strings != None:
               if type(from_strings) != list:
                   raise AssertionError("input is not a list")
               if len(from_strings) != size:
                   raise AssertionError("length of input list does not match size")
               for i in range(size):
                   if type(from_strings[i]) != str:
                       raise AssertionError("row " + str(i) + " is not a string")
                   if len(from_strings[i]) != size:
                       raise AssertionError("length of row " + str(i) + " does not match size")
                   for j in range(size):
                       if from_strings[i][j] not in ".@O":
                           raise AssertionError("invalid character in row " + str(i))
        self.size = size
        self.grid = [['E'] * size for _ in range(size)]
        self.from_strings = [] if from_strings is None else from_strings
        self.board= Board
        #self.from_strings=from_strings


    def get_size(self): #Returns the size of the grid created by the constructor
        return self.size

    def __str__(self):  # creating the grid
        padding = ' '  # Creating a variable with a space assigned so that it acts as a padding to the rows that have a single digit
        heading = '   ' + ' '.join(letters[:self.size])  # Alphabetical heading is created
        lines = [heading]  # adding the alphabetical heading into a list named lines to which the rows will be added later
        for r, row in enumerate(self.grid):
            if len(self.grid) < 10:  # for the grid with a size less than 10 to add the space to the start of the row for the single digits to be aligned
                if (self.from_strings):
                    line = " " + f'{self.size - r} ' + ' '.join(self.from_strings[r])
                else:
                    line = " " + f'{self.size - r} ' + ' '.join(self.points[x] for x in row)
                lines.append(line)
            else:  # for the grids that are larger than 9
                if r > 9:  # for rows 1 to 9 the single digits are aligned according to the first digit from the right of the two digit rows
                    if (self.from_strings):
                        line = f'{self.size - r} ' + ' '.join(self.from_strings[r])
                    else:
                        line = f'{self.size - r} ' + ' '.join(self.points[x] for x in row)
                    line = padding + line  # adding the space using the variable padding to the row created
                    lines.append(line)  # adding the row to the list of rows
                else:  # for the rows 10 onwards - as there is no requirement to add a padding it is not added here
                    if (self.from_strings):
                        line = f'{self.size - r} ' + ' '.join(self.from_strings[r])
                    else:
                        line = f'{self.size - r} ' + ' '.join(self.points[x] for x in row)  # creation of the row
                    lines.append(line)  # adding the newly created row to the list of rows
        return '\n'.join(lines)

    def _to_row_and_column(self, coords):
        # destructure coordinates like "B2" to "B" and 2
        alpha, num = coords
        colnum = ord(alpha) - ord('A') + 1
        rownum = self.size - int(num) + 1
        assert 1 <= rownum <= self.size,"row out of range"
        assert 1 <= colnum <= self.size,'column out of range'
        return rownum, colnum

    def set_colour(self, coords, colour_name):
        rownum, colnum = self._to_row_and_column(coords)
        assert len(coords)==2 or len(coords)==3, "invalid coordinates"
        assert colour_name in self.points,"invalid colour name"
        self.grid[rownum - 1][colnum - 1] = colour_name

    def get_colour(self, coords):
        rownum, colnum = self._to_row_and_column(coords)
        return self.grid[rownum - 1][colnum - 1]

    def to_strings(self):
          padding = ' '
          lines = []
          for r, row in enumerate(self.grid):
                 if self.from_strings:
                      lines.append(''.join(self.from_strings[r]))
                 else:
                      lines.append(''.join(self.points[x] for x in row))
          return lines

    def to_integer(self):
        digit_colour=""
        for line in self.to_strings():
            for character in line:
                if character=='.':
                    character=0
                elif character=='O':
                    character=1
                elif character=='@':
                    character=2
                character=str(character)
                digit_colour+=character
        return int(digit_colour,3)


       # return ''.join(self.to_int[x] for line in self.grid for x in line)


    def set_from_integer(self, integer_encoding):
        n = int(integer_encoding)
        list1 = []
        p=[]
        m=[]
        t=[]
        while n != 0:
            rem = n % 3
            list1.append(rem)
            n = n // 3
        list1.reverse()
        list1=["." if item ==0 else item for item in list1]
        list1=["O" if item ==1 else item for item in list1]
        list1=["@" if item ==2 else item for item in list1]
        for i in range(0,len(list1),3):
            p.append(list1[i:i+3])
        #print(p)
        for x in p:
            m=''.join(map(str,x))
            t.append(m)
        #print(Board(self.size,t))
        self.from_strings=t


    def fill_reaching(self,colour_name,reach_name, visited, r, c):
        new_list=[]
        new_list2=[]
        for x in self.from_strings:
            for y in x:
                 if y==".":
                     y="E"
                 elif y=="@":
                     y="B"
                 elif y=="O":
                     y="W"
                 new_list.append(y)
        for i in range(0, len(new_list), self.size):
            new_list2.append(new_list[i:i + self.size])
        self.grid=new_list2
        if r < 0 or r >= self.size or c < 0 or c >= self.size: #Checking whether the number of rows are within the size of the grid
            return False
        if visited[r][c] or self.grid[r][c] != colour_name:#Checking whether the number of columns are within the size of the grid
            return False
        if self.grid[r][c] == reach_name:
            return False
        visited[r][c] = True

        if self.fill_reaching(colour_name, reach_name, visited, r + 1, c):
            return True
        if self.fill_reaching(colour_name, reach_name, visited, r - 1, c):
            return True
        if self.fill_reaching(colour_name, reach_name, visited, r, c + 1):
            return True
        if self.fill_reaching(colour_name, reach_name, visited, r, c - 1):
            return True
        return False



#Test cases
b = Board(3, ["@O.", "OOO", ".O."])
print(b)
visited = [[False] * 3 for i in range(3)]
e = b.fill_reaching("W", "E", visited, 1, 1)
print(e)
print(visited)
visited = [[False] * 3 for i in range(3)]
e = b.fill_reaching("B", "E", visited, 0, 0)
print(e)
print(visited)
visited = [[False] * 3 for i in range(3)]
e = b.fill_reaching("W", "E", visited, 0, 0)
print(e)
print(visited)
```

My code is shown above

however the output i get is

```
   A B C
 3 @ O .
 2 O O O
 1 . O .
False
[[False, True, False], [True, True, True], [False, True, False]]
False
[[True, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
False
[[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

the expected output is :

```
   A B C
 3 @ O .
 2 O O O
 1 . O .

True
[[False, True, False], [True, True, True], [False, True, False]]
False
[[True, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
False
[[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
```

Please help me out cause I'm confused right now. Please provide me a rectified version of my code

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? See also: [ask]. ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question? You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Hi @starball my issue is that the code I've come up with doesn't provide the expected output and I'm confused about how to rectify it

Comment: `if self.grid[r][c] == reach_name: return False` -- should return True, I think? Currently there is no circumstance in which it can ever return True.

Comment: so i want to know what i need to change and the modifications required

Comment: @Stuart I tried that and it still gives me the same output

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger or `print`s to figure out which branch of `fill_reaching` is causing it to return False every time?

Comment: Your board is not initiated correctly. `b.grid` is `[[['E', 'E', 'E'], ['E', 'E', 'E'], ['E', 'E', 'E']]`

Comment: In fact there is nothing in your code that sets the grid based on the user's input.

Comment: Can I know what i can do about it

Answer (score 0):

Your need to ensure that there is some condition under which the method will return `True` without recursing - otherwise it can never return `True`.

However a bigger problem is that you are not initiating your board properly - it sets the `grid` to an array of empty squares even though `print(b)` shows a board with pieces on it.

This shows how you could initiate it properly and make the flood fill method can work with a minor change to the sequence of conditions.

```
class Board:
    points = {".": "E", "@": "B", "O": "W"}

    def __init__(self, rows):
        self.size = len(rows)
        self.grid = [[self.points[cell] for cell in row] for row in rows]

    def fill_reaching(self, colour_name, reach_name, visited, r, c):
        if r < 0 or r >= self.size or c < 0 or c >= self.size: #Checking whether the number of rows are within the size of the grid
            return False
        if self.grid[r][c] == reach_name:  # check this first
            return True
        if visited[r][c] or self.grid[r][c] != colour_name:#Checking whether the number of columns are within the size of the grid
            return False
        visited[r][c] = True
        
        if self.fill_reaching(colour_name, reach_name, visited, r + 1, c):
            return True
        if self.fill_reaching(colour_name, reach_name, visited, r - 1, c):
            return True
        if self.fill_reaching(colour_name, reach_name, visited, r, c + 1):
            return True
        if self.fill_reaching(colour_name, reach_name, visited, r, c - 1):
            return True
        return False

# Initiate like this
b = Board(["@O.", "OOO", ".O."])

# Test cases
print(b)
visited = b.false_grid()
e = b.fill_reaching("W", "E", visited, 1, 1)
print(e)
print(visited) 
# etc.
```

Comment: Thank you so much but how can i initiate my board properly cause i can't change the test cases according to my exercise

Comment: That's a different question - you could ask a new question focusing only on the initiation parts of the class

Comment: so other than for that the method is correct is it ?

Comment: is it okay if i add self.grid=self.from_strings so that the grid gets updated into that particular state

Comment: The `fill_reaching` method works with the changes shown above. Setting `self.grid=self.from_strings` won't work because they store the grid information differently.

Comment: i kinda figured out a way to update the grid

Comment: but it doesn't give the entirely correct output tho and the question is modified accordingly @Stuart

Comment: @Anne_Music no, your attempt won't quite work. Altered the code above so it shows a way to achieve this.